# Making a corrplot from CrossTable function in gmodels

Tags: r, chi-squared, r-corrplot

I wanted to assess the chi-squared statistic of 2 binary variables, ethnicity and sex, in my dataset using the CrossTable function from `gmodels` package and then visualize the residuals using `corrplot` package. This is my code in R:

```
#Loading libraries

library(gmodels)

library(corrplot)

#Dataset

Datavisit1<- read_excel("~/Downloads/Datavisit1.xlsx")
Datavisit1 <- structure(list(PATIENTID = c(1548, 2371, 3843, 9573, 3352, 8590, 6217, 8503, 6610, 2783), DX = c("AS", "AS", "AS", "RA", "AS", "RA", "AS", "RA", "AS", "RA"), AGE = c(22, 74, 18, 22, 59, 45, 33, 20, 32, 60), ETH = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), SEX = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) 
# replaced the useless call to load an Excel file the we don't have with comment.

#CrossTable

ethsex<- with(Datavisit1, CrossTable(ETH, SEX, prop.r = FALSE, prop.chisq = FALSE, 
                     prop.t = FALSE, chisq = TRUE, resid = TRUE, format = "SPSS"))

#Making Corrplot by extracting residuals from previous step

corrplot(ethsex$residuals, is.corr = FALSE)
```

I am getting the error saying I need matrix or dataframe. Can someone please help with what I am doing wrongly? Essentially, I want to get a nice graph like this but for a 2x2 situation (ethnicity and sex):

[Corrplot graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYpGP.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please share `dput(head(Datavisit1, 10))`?, in this way we can reproduce the example and try to give you an answer.

Comment: A guess would be to delete `format=SPSS` from `CrossTable()` as you are working with an excel file and coerce `ethsex` to a data.frame with `as.data.frame(ethsex)`

Comment: @AlvaroMartinez the answer to your first comment is: structure(list(PATIENTID = c(1548, 2371, 3843, 9573, 3352, 8590, 
6217, 8503, 6610, 2783), DX = c("AS", "AS", "AS", "RA", "AS", 
"RA", "AS", "RA", "AS", "RA"), AGE = c(22, 74, 18, 22, 59, 45, 
33, 20, 32, 60), ETH = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), SEX = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: For `ethsex$residuals` I get `NULL`. and from ` str(ethsex)` I likewise get `NULL`. Are you sure yoiu are supposed to be using `CrossTable` to create an object for subsequent work? If you wanted a crosstabulation, why not use `table`?

Comment: @IRTFM I am getting NULL too. I don't think my code to extract residuals from the CrossTable function is correct....

Comment: @IRTFM I am trying to make a contingency table and from that, I am trying to get the chi-squared statistic and residuals (according to http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~stine/r_companion/_book/association-between-categorical-variables.html). I don't know how the residuals can be extracted in order to feed into corrplot...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be well documented but omitting the `format="SPSS"` argument lets you get a result. It further turns out that the residuals are a sublist of the list item named "chisq"m

```
str(ethsex) 
# ... removed a bunch of output lines
 $ chisq     :List of 9
  ..$ statistic: Named num 2.86
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "X-squared"
  ..$ parameter: Named int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "df"
  ..$ p.value  : num 0.091
  ..$ method   : chr "Pearson's Chi-squared test"
  ..$ data.name: chr "t"
  ..$ observed : 'table' int [1:2, 1:2] 3 4 3 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ x: chr [1:2] "0" "1"
  .. .. ..$ y: chr [1:2] "0" "1"
  ..$ expected : num [1:2, 1:2] 4.2 2.8 1.8 1.2
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ x: chr [1:2] "0" "1"
  .. .. ..$ y: chr [1:2] "0" "1"
  ..$ residuals: 'table' num [1:2, 1:2] -0.586 0.717 0.894 -1.095
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ x: chr [1:2] "0" "1"
  .. .. ..$ y: chr [1:2] "0" "1"
  ..$ stdres   : 'table' num [1:2, 1:2] -1.69 1.69 1.69 -1.69
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ x: chr [1:2] "0" "1"
  .. .. ..$ y: chr [1:2] "0" "1"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

So this would be the needed code after removing the cause of the failure:

```
corrplot(ethsex$chisq$residuals, is.corr = FALSE)
```

If you wanted to be good citizen of the R community you could send a note about this infelicity to the package maintainer: You can find his email address with this code.

```
 maintainer("gmodels")
 #[1] "Gregory R. Warnes <greg@warnes.net>"
```